# How can I save a PHLivePhoto to photo library?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, phlivephoto

I am new in Swift and I am developing an app that picks a live photo from the library and displays it on an imageview, until that part it works, but the imageview is on top of another imageview that has a custom image(like a background image). By the moment when I hit the save button it only stores the image view with the custom background. I am using the following code to store it on the library:

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myView.image!)
let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
```

This code is of course on the save button.

what I want to do is to give the user that ability to store both things at the same time, like for example:

I have an imageview with an image of a galaxy as background and on top of it I have an imageview displaying a live photo, so I want to store both things to the library and when I check it on the library I will have a new live photo with a background of a galaxy.

I don't know if somebody will understand the example, but is I think it is the best I can do to describe the problem.

**
this is the example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0xso.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the `selectedImage` on top of the `backgroundImage`, and save the result.

Add this extension of `UIImage`

```
extension UIImage {
    func saveImage(withImage image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        // create image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let centeredFrame = CGRect(x: (size.width - image.size.width)/2, y: (size.height - image.size.height)/2, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
        image.draw(in: centeredFrame)
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }
}
```

And use it

```
if let newImage = backgroundImage.saveImage(withImage: userImage), let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage), let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Where `backgroundImage` is custom background and `userImage` is live photo selected from user library.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I am having some problems trying to add that code to my code :(

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: I guess I have to change the "backgroundImage" to what It is the piece of code that is refering to my background right? like to the outlet? 

The thing is that I change it and it seems not to have a member for "size"

Comment: i have added to my question a foto, can you please check it?

Comment: backgroundImage is `UIImage` type and it has a [size property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624105-size), do not confuse with `UIImageView`. Have you tried the code?

Comment: well, I made a new outlet for the UIImage, and I have added the code but I am having troubles with  the "draw" from the second line:

draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ImageView.size.width, height: ImageView.size.height))

the error message says : use of unresolved identifier "draw"

did you saw the photo I added to my question?

Comment: I updated my answer with a compiling version, let me know how it works.

Comment: i have added the code but now i am having troubles with the "userImage" as it is a PHLivephotoView it throws me:
"Cannot convert value of type 'PHLivephotoView!' to expected argument type 'UIImage'".